# What justify the division of power series?

Tags: real-analysis, power-series

It is sometimes seen that people divide power series of two functions $f$ and $g$ to get the power series representation of $\frac{f}{g}$.

For example, $\tan x=\frac{\sin x}{\cos x}$, so compute $\frac{x-\frac{1}{3!}x^3+\frac{1}{5!}x^5-\cdots}{1-\frac{1}{2!}x^2+\frac{1}{4!}x^4-\cdots}$ as if it were two finite polynomials by long division, and get the quotient of first few terms, and see the pattern of what this whole power series are.

However, I haven't read any analysis books which mentioned the division of power series.  What justifies doing so? Why is it valid? Is there something we should be careful when doing this? Why we can do the traditional long divison on *infinite* terms polynomials?

Comment: Then, you probably should read analysis books. Every search engine gives lots of results for "division of power series", and the list under "Related" on the right-hand side of your questions shows at least two.

Comment: Do you understand *multiplication* of power series?